# React Native get data in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, react-native

Good day I am using Response Native. I want to pull data from MYSQL database with Response Native without using PHP. I cannot retrieve data from the MYSQL port. I want to search the MYSQL database. In the second code that I pay, I am processing the server. I want a select sql command in the MySQL database. I want to run the select command in MYSQL based on the itemsUSERNAME data.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  ...
});

export default class usrFirst extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
     itemsUSERNAME:[],
}
connection.connect()

 componentDidMount() {
connection.query('SELECT ID from solution where itemsUSERNAME', function (err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err
})

connection.end()
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also new to react native. But here's how I achieved your goal.

I created a helping method in react native to fetch data from server.

```
responseList() {
    fetch('YOUR API', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            data: itemsUSERNAME
        })

    }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            this.setState({ package: responseJson.results });
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
}
```

Then I called it in `componentWillMount()`.

```
componentWillMount(){
    this.responseList();
}
```

Then I created the backend code like this.

```
<?php include 'db.php'; ?>
<?php

$arr = array();
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

$obj = json_decode($json, true);

$data = $obj['data'];

$sql = "SELECT ID from solution where itemsUSERNAME = '" . $data . "'"; // This is just my code example.

$result_set = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($result_set)) {
    array_push($arr, $result);
}

$responseJson = json_encode(array('results' => $arr));
echo $responseJson;
```

Hope this helps.